# Read Data into Time Series Object in R

Tags: r, time-series

My data looks as follows:

```
Month/Year;Number
01/2010; 1.0
02/2010;19.0
03/2010; 1.0
...
```

How can I read this into a `ts(object)` in `R`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (assuming your data is called `df`)

```
ts(df$Number, start = c(2010, 01), frequency = 12)
##      Jan Feb Mar
## 2010   1  19   1
```

---

Edit: this will work only if you don't have missing dates and your data is in correct order. For a more general solution see @Anandas answer below

Comment: First of all thanks. I forgot to say that my data is not in the workplace of R but in a text file data.txt. How can I read it from the text file and store it into the ts object?

Comment: You could use something like `df <- read.csv("yourdata.txt", sep = ";")`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `zoo` as a starting point. This will ensure that if there are any month/year combinations missing, they would be handled properly.

Example (notice that data for April is missing):

```
mydf <- data.frame(Month.Year = c("01/2010", "02/2010", "03/2010", "05/2010"),
                   Number = c(1, 19, 1, 12))
mydf
#   Month.Year Number
# 1    01/2010      1
# 2    02/2010     19
# 3    03/2010      1
# 4    05/2010     12

library(zoo)
as.ts(zoo(mydf$Number, as.yearmon(mydf$Month.Year, "%m/%Y")))
#      Jan Feb Mar Apr May
# 2010   1  19   1  NA  12
```